# Using Parse API on Android: Application is misconfigured for Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com API to connect my application to Facebook and share some data.

I have checked the Parse.initialize in my code, it has the correct keys. I have checked the ParseFacebookUtils.initialize in my code and it has the correct Facebook app Id. I have checked the settings on my parse account and facebook authentication is enabled and the facebook app id is set correctly.

No idea why I can not connect to facebook through Parse.

Btw, If I delete Facebook official app, the problem gets solved, but if it is installed on my device, I start getting this issue.

Am I missing something to check ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem ...

It was related to the key hash registered on facebook.
To those guys who experience this problem, I recommend to check the key hash you get on your developing pc and check if this key hash is registered on facebook for your app.

In case you are new like me and have no idea how doing key hash related stuff, check this link :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/